# How do you join multiple rows into one row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list that I'm trying to add to a dataframe. It looks something like this:

```
list_one = ['apple','banana','cherry',' ', 'grape', 'orange', 'pineapple','']
```

If I add the list to a dataframe, using `df = pd.DataFrame({'list_one':list_one})` it'll look like this:

```
       list_one
   -------------
   0   apple
   1   banana 
   2   cherry
   3  
   4   grape
   5   orange
   6   pineapple
   7
```

I want the combine some of the rows into one row, so that the dataframe looks something like this:

```
       list_one
   -----------------------------
   0   apple, banana, cherry 
   1   grape, orange, pineapple
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you for taking the time to read my question and help in any way you can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create mask for match words by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), invert by `~` and crate groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), filter only matched rows and pass to [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `join` function:

```
m = df['list_one'].str.contains('\w+')
df = df[m].groupby((~m).cumsum(), as_index=False).agg(', '.join)
print (df)
                   list_one
0     apple, banana, cherry
1  grape, orange, pineapple
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `groupby` and `agg`:

```
>>> df.groupby(df.loc[df['list_one'].str.contains('\w+')].index.to_series().diff().ne(1).cumsum(), as_index=False).agg(', '.join)
                   list_one
0     apple, banana, cherry
1  grape, orange, pineapple
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. Your solution didn't work, but I still really appreciate the effort. It was really similar to the solution above, just with slight variations. Thank you again!